# C++ '-' operator on 'Matrix' class

Tags: c++, matrix, operators, overloading, subtraction

So I have a Matrix class that returns an array of doubles, e.g:

```
Matrix A = {0,1,2}
           {3,4,5}

Matrix B = {5,6,7}
           {8,9,10}
```

I want to perform the operation:

```
Matrix C = A - B;
```

I know that the logic would be to call a member function that notices the '-' operator, 
and have it subtract each element from each other

e.g

```
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       C[i] = A[i] - B[i]; 
    }
```

Am I correct in thinking this and how would I implement this? How do I invoke the operator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at operator overloading in C++.

Comment: You're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading. More specifically, for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

To do the operation like this:

```
Matrix C = A - B;
```

You will need to overload the '-' operator for your Matrix class and define the subtraction behavior there. Refer to [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for an introduction.

Comment: But how can you do the same thing with third party class such as set? Having a function set<T> Subtract(set<T> A, set<T> B) does not count.